# Table Inside UIView not scrolling or receiving touches

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout, uitouch, sdcalertview

I'm making app where I use `SDCAlertView`(https://github.com/Scott90/SDCAlertView) and its `contentView` property in order to display an `UITableView`. The problem occurs when I try to scroll through the table.

Here is how I allocate the alert:

```
    SDCAlertView *soundAlertView = [[SDCAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Select Sound" message:@"Select a sound." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

    //Give the alert a tag for later id'ing
    soundAlertView.tag = 2;
```

This is how I create the table and then add it to the subview of the alert:

```
//Create the tableview controller
    SelectionViewController *soundSelection = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"selectionCont"];

    //assign the table to a local var
    UITableView *table = soundSelection.tableView;
    UIView *tableHolderView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(table.frame.origin.x, table.frame.origin.y, soundAlertView.contentView.frame.size.width, 200)];

    [tableHolderView addSubview:table];


    //Add the table view to the alert view
    [soundAlertView.contentView addSubview:tableHolderView];
```

I then add constraints to make the tableview fit in the alert, and then show the alert:

```
   //Make sure the tableview fits in the alert
    [soundAlertView.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[tableHolderView]|"
                                                                              options:0
                                                                              metrics:nil
                                                                                views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(tableHolderView)]];
    [soundAlertView show];
```

After Doing research, I found that I should probably pass the touches from the `contentView` to the `contanerView` to the `tableView`. While this would work, it requires subclassing and I can't subclass to the access to the `contentView` property.

How do I get the `tableView` to recognize the touches and scrolls that are recognized by the `contentView` of the alert?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ive Figured it Out, the trick was to subclass `SDCAlertView` itself and then sending `hitTest:` to the tableview.

Answer (score 0):

Setting BOUNCES UITableView's property to YES, solves to me.